# Powershell function return value not stored in variable

Tags: powershell

I cannot figure out how to write a simple function in PowerShell. I'm a C# developer so maybe there's some mind-bending PowerShell construct that I'm not aware of.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
function ToBase64([string] $input) {
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($input)
    return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
}

$encoded = ToBase64 -input "Hello World"

Write-Host "Encoded: $encoded"
```

I would expect this output:

```
Encoded: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
```

But I'm just getting an empty string:

```
Encoded:
```

There are no errors reported by PowerShell itself.

I'm invoking this script like this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "base64.ps1"
```

I'm totally lost here. I tried googling for this problem but everything I've found suggests that this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function ToBase64{
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($args[0])
    return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
}

$encoded = ToBase64 -input "Hello World"

Write-Host "Encoded: $encoded"
```

Comment: If you get rid of the `-input` it works - but I'd like to learn why my approach isn't working.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski Because `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables). See the answer to the question I marked yours as a duplicate of.